# WCF Transport Security

Tags: c#, wcf, wcf-security

i have WSHttpBinding and ServiceHost in my code. how can i set httpsGetEnabled and 
mexHttpsBinding from code behind?

Answer (score 1):

```
ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(MyService));
ServiceMetadataBehavior metadataBehavior;
metadataBehavior = host.Description.Behaviors.Find<ServiceMetadataBehavior>();

if(metadataBehavior == null)
{
    Debug.Assert(BaseAddresses.Any(baseAddress=>baseAddress.Uri.Scheme == "http"));
    metadataBehavior = new ServiceMetadataBehavior();
    metadataBehavior.HttpGetEnabled = true;
    host.Description.Behaviors.Add(metadataBehavior);
}

host.Open();
```